# Login Attempts Servlet - Disable user for 10 mins if user fail all 3 login attempt

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have been intensively research on how we can do a validation on login attempts in servlet .

For an example. 

1) if user logs in incorrect password // it will return back to login page
2) User will only have 3 attempts.
3) After failing to log in in their 3rd attempt. They will be banned for 10mins

login.jsp

```
<form action = "loginController"> 
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

As for our servlet file
**loginController.java** 

i understand we have to assigned session to username so that each username will have a unique session id append to it but i am really unsure how we can do it.

```
doPost(HttpServletRequest...)
{ 
String name = request.getParameter("username");
String pass = request.getParameter("password");

//we will create session and append it to username
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("username" , name);

//what im really unsure is how we can get the sessionID to telly with the username
int countAttempt = new Integer(0);
if(countAttempt <= 3){
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
} else if(countAttempt == 3){
//This will ban users to log in for 10mins....
}
```

This is easily achievable in core java platform in my previous module, where else for servlet which require us to communicate with the controller and back to jsp is quite a challenge.

Any Help will be greatly appreaciated

Comment: unsure?? Explain briefly that what all problems you are facing

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you to figure out your problem, In my solution iam adding new attribute to the session "count" which carry the current login attempt

```
 doPost(HttpServletRequest...)
    { 
    String name = request.getParameter("username");
    String pass = request.getParameter("password");


    //we will create session and append it to username
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("username" , name);
    session.setAttribute("count",new Integer(0));
    int countAttempt = ((Integer)session.getAttribute("count")).intValue();
    //what im really unsure is how we can get the sessionID to telly with the username
    if(countAttempt <= 3){
    session.setAttribute("count",++countAttempt);
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    } else if(countAttempt == 3){
    //This will ban users to log in for 10mins....
    }
```

Comment: i tried your your solution but it does not recognize if the same username tried to attempt more than 3 times. 

For an example . i did , if(name.equals("test") && !pass.equals("abc")){
i added your code.
} else {
//success login
}

Comment: I think you should made a table in database which store the detail of current login attempt by user.

Answer (score 1):

Something like below answer will give you brief idea about implementation

```
//inside servlet
 int login_attempts = 3; 

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {

response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

     String email = request.getParameter("email");
     String pass = request.getParameter("password");

 try{

     Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement ps =con.prepareStatement("select * from user 
     where mail=? and password=? and account_lock=0 ");
     ps.setString(1, email);
     ps.setString(2, pass);
     ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();
     if(rs.next())
     { 
     String userdbName = rs.getString("user_name");
     String customer_id = rs.getString("customer_id");
     /*String account_status = rs.getString("account_lock");
      int bool1 = Integer.parseInt(account_status);
     */

     HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
     session.setAttribute("name",userdbName);  
     session.setAttribute("cid",customer_id);
     response.sendRedirect("personal/home.jsp"); 
     }

     else{
       if(login_attempts==0)
        {
         System.out.println("No Login Attempts Available");
        }
       else
        {
         login_attempts=login_attempts-1;
    System.out.println("Login Failed Now Only "+login_attempts+" 
         Login Attempts Available");
         if(login_attempts==0)
          {
         System.out.println("your account block.contact admin for 
         login.");
          }
        } 

     }  
     response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");

      }

      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

     }
```

Comment: @Farid Avesko Arshad if it helped you, appreciate it with an upvote and acceptance using green tick.

Comment: Hi @Bhargav Modi, i did the above code. However , there is something i dont get it. in your if(rs.next()){......} // this part. i dont get .......  shouldnt i do a while loop ? because im checking my table if role == admin. it will redirect to admin page and if role == cust , it will redirect to customer page. On the other hand.  i get the logic for login_attemp == 0 (it will flag the user) .. the problem i face is , once it redirect to login page again. on my second try. it will still says login try is left with 2 instead of decrement to one

Comment: For example , i have this code .. lets ignore the database connection.. ii just want to create if attempt is more than 3 times. it will block users.

`HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
     session.setAttribute("name",name);  
     String sessionName = (String) session.getAttribute("name");`

Comment: `if(name.equals("farid")){
   
   if(pass.equals("abc"))
   {
   pw.println(("Success"));
   pw.println(sessionName);
   }
   else {
    login_attempt = login_attempt - 1;
    if(login_attempt < 3 && sessionName.equals(name)){
     pw.println(" You have this try " + login_attempt + " : " + sessionName);
    } else if(login_attempt == 0 && sessionName.equals(name)){
     pw.println("Please contact admin for as your account is blocked");
    }`

Comment: But the problem is , this wont decrement the the login attempt ...

It will also state 2 times whenever i try to log in using the same username